# WP8 / Cordova filesystem - does anyone know the correct code?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins, html5-filesystem

There is a serious lack of documentation on how to use the Cordova file plugin with the WP8 platform.

I've got an app on Android, fireOS and iOS, all using the file plugin to view directory contents, download, save and open generated files from my webservice which all use the following code:

```
function listDir() {
//console.log('listDir');
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    //console.log('gotFS. filesystem.root = ' + fileSystem.root.value);
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("MyFolder", { create: true, exclusive: false }, gotDir);

}

function gotDir(dirEntry) {
    //console.log('gotDir');
    // Get a directory reader
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

    // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
    directoryReader.readEntries(success, fail);

}

function success(entries) {
    var i = 0, sb = '';
    sb += '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="pdfFiles">';
    if (entries.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            sb += '<li><a href="#" data-src="' + entries[i].toURL() + '"><img src="images/icons/icon_pdf.png" class="ui-li-icon" width="16px" height="16px" alt="PDF Icon" />';
            sb += entries[i].name;
            //sb += '<br />';
            //sb += entries[i].fullPath;
            sb += '</a></li>';
        }
    } else {
        sb += '<li><p>You do not have any saved reports</p></li>';
    }

    sb += '</ul>';
    $('#pdfReports-entries').html(sb);
    $('ul#pdfFiles').listview().listview('refresh');

    //open the pdf file using the fileOpener plugin
    $('ul#pdfFiles li a').on('click', function () {

        $this = $(this);
        window.plugins.fileOpener.open($this.attr('data-src'));
    });
}

function fail(error) {
    logError("Failed to list directory contents: " + error.code);
    sb += '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="pdfFiles">';
    sb += '<li><p>You do not have any saved reports</p></li>';

    sb += '</ul>';
    $('#pdfReports-entries').html(sb);
    $('ul#pdfFiles').listview().listview('refresh');
}
```

}

WP8 throws the following error at the gotFS function:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

I then tried the code at [this Github](https://apache.googlesource.com/cordova-wp8/+/a31708455c3cbe56dcec79e444e70b60a5fbeb54/example/www/file.html), which still failed to create or read any directories, but didn't throw the IsolatedStorageException exception.

I've asked Google many times, but it is unable to give a coherent answer.

Does *anyone* know how to use the file plugin with WP8?

Comment: You got my +1 vote at "There is a serious lack of documentation" :) Just a guess, but did you make sure to give your app permissions to access the file system?

Comment: Your question illustrates my point exactly! Where / how would I check or enable that?

Comment: I tried this but `fileSystem.root.value` is `undefined`. Does this only work on the device and not on an emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to my comment above, but wanted a place to put code...

I haven't done a WP8 app myself, only iOS and Android, but maybe the app doesn't have the right permissions?

These would go in your `Properties/WPAppManifest.xml` file, and look like:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE" />
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" />
</Capabilities>
```

And the list of available capability IDs is [listed here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx).
Though the only one I see related to file storage is `ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE` so maybe that isn't the issue... I figured the link above might be useful though.

Comment: That is exactly the answer. Adding ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE to WPAppManifest.xml allowed my second code example to run. Note to Apache Cordova; when enabling WP8 filesystem, also update the manifest. Thank you, @CodingWithSpike, for resolving this.

Comment: 23 hours later and unfortunately this doesn't appear to be the whole answer :(. window.requestFileSystem async request seems to be very slow on WP8 and will return undefined -so I've moved that request to an app load event (using promises would be better). Yet still WP8 refuses to comply with all of the other Cordova platform filesystem plugins.

Comment: Adding ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE  worked for me, not file api worked great. thanks